# Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 takes forever to load

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Has anybody faced this issue? You start Visual Studio 2015, the splash image shows but does not load Visual Studio for more than 10 mins. Anybody know a fix for this?

Comment: is there something in Task Manager with high CPU/Disk usage while starting?

Comment: No, infact it is almost 0 CPU and Disk usage. It stays there in that state for long time. Even if I open another instance, they just sit there with 0 CPU and disk usage

Comment: Check it with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to understand what it is doing and update the question with your findings.

Comment: Process Monitor does not show any activity for Visual Studio. However if i kill the Vsdev.exe and restart, it loads faster. Temporary workaround for now.